# How to get rid of black lines over finished render images?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]
there are unintntional black lines which appears only in final rendered image. how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have enabled freestyle render wich is responsible for these black lines. So to fix the problem you have to look for „freestyle render“ in the render tab and disable it.